# Help finishing the proof of a vector identity

Tags: vectors

I have a homework problem that says "if $a\times b=a-b$, prove $a=b$"
I first started by computing the cross product:
$a\times b =\left|\begin{matrix} 
i & j & k \\
a_1 & a_2 & a_3 \\
b_1 & b_2 & b_3 \\
\end{matrix}\right| = (a_2b_3-a_3b_2,a_3b_1-a_1b_3,a_1b_2-a_2b_1)$

I then set each component of that vector equal to the respective component of $a-b$ and got that
$\begin{array}{lr}
a_2b_3-a_3b_2=a_1-b_1\\
a_3b_1-a_1b_3=a_2-b_2\\
a_1b_2-a_2b_1=a_3-b_3\\
\end{array}$

Any tips or suggestions where to go from here?

Comment: A rewording of Sassatelli Giulio's answer with more geometry and less notation: $a-b$ is in the span of $\{a,b\}$.  $a \times b$ is perpendicular to that plane.  The only vector that is both in that plane and perpendicular to that plane must be $0$, hence $a \times b = 0 = a-b$, therefore $a=b$.